# Tor Browser Bundle can not establish a connection

Tags: linux, tor, linux-mint, tor-browser-bundle

I installed tor on my Linux Mint Nadia but the bundle stuck in "establishing an encrypted directory connection" and does not go forward.

What should I do ?

Comment: Could you provide some information about your internet connection and tell in what country you are using it?

Comment: @qbi my country is iran.

Comment: Most likely you are behind a firewall that is blocking the port that Tor runs on. Try the "My firewall only lets me connect to certain ports" option with port `80` and port `443` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to change the default bridges and try again.

Check [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/cant-connect-tor-network-failed-to-establish-network/4920#4920) question on [tor.stackexchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/).

To have a short review, go to `Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor` and open **torrc** file. [Get new bridges](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/get-tor-bridges-via-email/7473#7473) and copy them into the file. make sure to add **`UseBridges 1`**.

Comment: Thanks for your late answer. Maybe you could copy a relevant part from the reference you gave (change the default bridge).